# Handling stateful logic in websocket server instances connected by redis

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, 12factor

I'm developing a web-based realtime game in Node where the Node server instances use redis as a common datastore. This works fine for simple things like storing the chat or data about each player. However, the game logic is contained in its own Javascript module - each instance of the game keeps track of a lot of state, including the game board and the history of the state after each move.

I see two options:

1. Keep the game objects in the node worker instances (balanced evenly among the instances, using load balancing by nginx for example). This is the approach used by a similar project that I inherited, but I didn't like it because after a deploy, the master node process had to restore the games to each worker node process. In this way it violates the [Twelve Factor guidelines](https://12factor.net/processes).
2. Store the game state in redis, and for example after a player makes a move, the node worker fetches the game state from redis, drops it into the game logic module, and does the move calculations. My primary concern with this approach is speed - the game state does not easily fit into redis data structures, so there would be a lot of JSON.parse and JSON.stringify calls while setting/getting the state from redis, unless I were to heavily rewrite the game logic to deal in more primitive data types.

My goal is to keep my node workers stateless so deploys are simpler while not making any big sacrifices in speed or efficiency using redis. Any ideas?

Comment: How many players are involved in a game?  Are all the players in a particular game on the same node instance?  Or might they be on separate node instances?  If all the players in a game aren't in the same node instance, you can't keep the state in a node instance unless you replicate all state to all node instances.

Comment: In the new system it's 2 players per game. The old one has 4 players and each player could be connected to a different node instance while the game was only on one instance, and a new move would be published on redis with all node instances receiving the move and only acting on it if that instance held the game. It works, but it still feels like the wrong way.

Comment: In the new system are the 2 players per game always on the same node instance or not?  You can really simplify things if you cause that to happen because then state can be kept local in the node instance which is a lot faster and simpler to manage.